# The problem with formulas in a table (pgfplotstable)

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have the file, that created dynamical by my program. For example:

```
a      b
$a_1$  0.121
$a_2$  0.001
$a_3$  0.031
```

Me need to convert him to a table (I use `pgfplotstable` package). But when I try to do it, LaTeX is hang up (I find out, that problem, perhaps, in formulas).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[] {mytable.txt}

\end{document}
```

I want to get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose the formulas inside brace pair and also let `pgfplotstable` know that column is not numbers so parsing should be off.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/a/.style={string type},
]{
a b
{$a_1$} 0.121
{$a_2$} 0.001
{$a_3$} 0.031
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's fantastic! Thank you very much! I spend so much time and didn't find anything about using brace pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `\scantable` macro for this purpose. No need of `pgfplotstable` or any other package. TeX primitive language is very powerful.

```
\def\scantwo#1 #2 {\ifx^#1^\else \printtwo{#1}{#2}\expandafter\scantwo\fi}
\def\printtwo#1#2{\hbox{\hbox to2em{\hfil#1\hfil}\kern.4em\hbox to3em{\hfil#2\hfil}}}
\def\scantable#1{{\everyeof={{} {} }\par \expandafter \scantwo \input #1 }}

\scantable{mytable.txt}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I prefer to use in my work `pgfplotstable` now because of his powerful capabilities of render tables. Nevertheless I will remember your advice.